# In scala, How could Map[_,_] and scala.collection.immutable.Map[_,_] have different TypeTag?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

They refer to the same thing, yet when I compare 2 type tags:

```
val ttg1 = typeTag[Map[_,_]]
val ttg2 = typeTag[immutable.Map[_,_]]

assert(ttg1.tpe == ttg2.tpe)
```

I got:

```
Map[_, _] did not equal scala.collection.immutable.Map[_,_]
ScalaTestFailureLocation: 
Expected :scala.collection.immutable.Map[_,_]
Actual   :Map[_, _]
```

How could this happen in a typed language? How do I make them identical?

**UPDATE:** for List this is more confusing:

```
val ttg1 = typeTag[List[_]]
val ttg2 = typeTag[immutable.List[_]]

assert(ttg1.tpe == ttg2.tpe)

List[_] did not equal List[_]
ScalaTestFailureLocation: 
Expected :List[_]
Actual   :List[_]
```

They are exactly the same thing! Yet reflection choose to ignore it.

Comment: do you have `scala.collection._` imported by some chance?

Comment: @Dima I have `scala.collection.immutable` imported, sorry forgot to copy the import, but you got my point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing type identity when it seems you really want type equivalence.  In

```
type A = B
```

`A` and `B` are two different types that are equivalent (which is why they have different type tags).  Try changing your test to

```
assert(ttg1.tpe =:= ttg2.tpe)
```

`=:=` on types tests equivalence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though it looks not simple for common programmers

Comment: I think it is safe to say that reflection is an intermediate-to-advanced topic.  Most programmers should not need to use it.